# WPF: Variable Number of Button Controls to Fill Available Space

Tags: .net, wpf

This feels like it should be simple...

I have a `DataGrid` and in it a `DataGridTemplateColumn` will have a variable number of horizontally stacked buttons in it - between 1 and 3 buttons. I'd like the buttons in each row to fill all the available space in that row.

e.g.

```
Row #1: Button 1 (100% width) 
Row #2: Button 1 (33% width), Button 2 (33% width), Button 3 (33% width) 
Row #3: Button 1 (100% width) 
Row #4: Button 1 (50% width), Button 2 (50% width)
```

`StackPanel`, `DockPanel`, `Grid` and `UniformGrid` don't seem to facilitate this, at least not in any way I can discern!

What should I be doing?

Comment: UniformGrid should be able to handle it. Please show your attempt

Comment: is the number of columns in the datagrid determined at runtime or is it static? if it is static, `uniformgrid` will handle it in the xaml. If not maybe you can databind to the `rows` property of it to make it dynamic as well.

Comment: I think that UniformGrid with Rows="1" should work...

Comment: UniformGrid has done it with ```Rows=1``` and ```HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"``` set on each of the buttons. If one of you who told me to look at ```UniformGrid``` again wants to answer, I'll mark as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution could be using **UniformGrid** with property **Rows** set to "1":

```
<UniformGrid Rows="1"/>
```

[UniformGrid MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: And just for posterity: make sure the buttons' ```HorizontalAlignment``` property is set to ```stretch```